# No touchpad gestures on Samsung Series 9 / 13.04

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, samsung, gestures

I recently installed 13.04 and like many others, my touchpad gestures do not work. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem on my PC was to enter the Ubuntu Software Centre!

Make a search for Synapstiks and download the 'Synapstiks Touchpad management' tool, it worked a treat for me.